# Grouping and finding the min and max in Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have input data as below:

```
Date         ID    Parameter1   Parameter2
1-June-2020   1    Enabled      Disabled
2-June-2020   1    Enabled      Disabled          
3-June-2020   1                 Enabled
4-June-2020   1    Enabled      Disabled
5-June-2020   1    Enabled      Disabled
7-June-2020   1    Enabled      Disabled
```

I need the output as below.

By doing this we are trying to avoid the duplicates and also keeping the track from when to when the values remained the same.

```
Output:
Date           ID Parameter1   Parameter2   minDate    MaxDate
1-June-2020    1  Enabled      Disabled     1st June   2nd June
3-June-2020    1               Enabled      3rd June   3rd June
4-June-2020    1  Enabled      Disabled     4th June   7th June
```

I tried using lead windowing function to check if the data is same or not. But not able to come up with an approach to find out the min and max date.

Currently, I have come up with the below solution:

```
sDF.withColumn("row_num1",row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("Date")))
 .withColumn("row_num2",row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("id","Parameter1","Parameter2")
   .orderBy("Date")))
   .select($"id", $"Parameter1", $"Parameter2",($"row_num1"-$"row_num2").alias("diff1"),$"Date")
   .groupBy("id", "Parameter1","Parameter2","diff1").agg(min("Date"),max("Date"))
   .orderBy(min("Date")).drop("diff1")
```

Comment: what did u try?

Comment: Hi - I have tried this for now, it's working fine

Comment: pls put in the question, that is how the site works, just indent 4 spaces and we can all easily see what u have done

Comment: als min date not required as the date covers that

Comment: Actually, it looks okay to me, so what is the question, the min and max are what?

Comment: OK, get it, interesting solution, what is the problem?

Comment: Actually I recognize the algorithm from the past, non-procedural approach. It seems fine.

Comment: I think you might need to retract the question as it is fine